# Nohup: Redirect stderr to file and dismiss stdout

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, nohup, stderr

Per default, `nohup` writes `stdout` to `nohup.out` and dismisses `stderr`. I would like to have it the other way around:

write `stderr` to a file and dismiss `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
nohup command 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

Because the first redirect is from STDERR to current handler of `STDOUT` it write to `nohup.out`. Then `STDOUT` is redirected to `NULL`

Comment: what about redirecting stderr to a file?

Comment: Let edit the answer (with usual `&`)

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect standard error to the file you want:

```
$ ls
test.sh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "out"
echo "error" 1>&2
$ ./test.sh
out
error
$ nohup ./test.sh < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> err.out
$ ls
err.out  test.sh
$ cat err.out
error
```

From the manual:

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file.  If standard output is a terminal, append output to `nohup.out` if possible, `$HOME/nohup.out` otherwise.  If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output.  To save output to FILE, use `nohup COMMAND > FILE`.

Given that it is silent if stderr is redirected, it stands to reason that it would behave normally, and, as shown above, it does.

Comment: this does not seem to work, I still see INFO messages in the err.out.

Comment: Unsure why; I just made my test more extensive (see edit) and it behaves as I expect and descrive.

Comment: maybe it is because the command is `java -jar ...`